# How do I run a graqphl query in gatsby-browser.js

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I want to run a graphql query inside `wrapRootComponent` / `replaceRouterComponent`. Both methods belong to the [gatsby browser API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/). From the documentation and the code I was unable to find a possibility to run a graphql query.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I am trying to achieve the same with `replaceRouterComponent` yet the component I want to replace pulls data from GraphQL. Any help in how you achieved this would be very helpful. Cheers.